# How do I display long list of client on a page using keynote

Tags: keynote

In keynote each page has a fixed size. Just to impress people I am developing a page which will list around 40 clients.

I want the list of client names to appear one after another and the list will scroll down.  Sort of like the reverse of a credits scroll at the end of a movie. How do I do that with Keynote?

For simplicity you can also imagine as having a single page that lists from 1 to 100 vertically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope I unterstood what you want...

I tried to create an example: [scroll_example.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2188000/scroll_example.zip)

**Follow these steps:**

1. Create all your client names
2. Group them all to one object (if they're all in one textbox, skip this step)
3. Create an action for that object -> Move
4. Set the action from bottom to top and specify the duration
5. Place your object outside your slide and end position of the move action is of course in your slide (see the example)

Comment: Providing an example is a good idea, I was trying to figure out how to describe what to do and passed on answering.

Comment: Thank you so much. I did not even know that this feature existed. Really appreciate it.

Comment: How to define the boundary for the ball movement inside the slide page? What I mean is that I don't want the ball movement from bottom of the screen to top of the screen. Instead I want to limit the movement in the area inside the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to do side to side you could add each item as a separate text item, and then apply a Drift build-in animation. Unfortunately Drift only does left to right, or right to left. But it provides a nice organic move in and move out with acceleration and deceleration.